# Having a problem with SDL2 and CMake Setup

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, sdl, sdl-2

I am using C++, SDL2 and CMake to create a game (in Visual Studio Code).
Sadly I am getting an error, that SDL2 can't be found.

I tried multiple ways to do it. My current solution is that I have an environment variable called `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` set to `G:\Coding\sdks`. In that folder there is 'SDL2-2.28.4' which is the SDL2-VC downloaded from GitHub.

```
SDL.h: No such file or directory
```

**This is my CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(sdl2_tutorial)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")

set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp src/game.cpp src/game.hpp)

include_directories(.)

add_executable(sdl2_tutorial ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(sdl2_tutorial SDL2::SDL2 SDL2::SDL2main)
```

**This is the output when trying to run or build the project:**

```
[main] Building folder: sdl2_tutorial 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build g:/Coding/sdl2_tutorial/build --config Debug --target ALL_BUILD -j 18 --
[build] MSBuild version 17.6.3+07e294721 for .NET Framework
[build] 
[build]   main.cpp
[build] SDL2main.lib(SDL_windows_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol SDL_main referenced in function main_getcmdline [G:\Coding\sdl2_tutorial\build\sdl2_tutorial.vcxproj]
[build]     Hint on symbols that are defined and could potentially match:
[build]       "int __cdecl SDL_main(int,char const * * const)" (?SDL_main@@YAHHQEAPEBD@Z)
[build] G:\Coding\sdl2_tutorial\bin\Debug\sdl2_tutorial.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals [G:\Coding\sdl2_tutorial\build\sdl2_tutorial.vcxproj]
[proc] The command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build g:/Coding/sdl2_tutorial/build --config Debug --target ALL_BUILD -j 18 -- exited with code: 1
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:02.242
[build] Build finished with exit code 1
```

**And here is the header file where it can't find SDL.h**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <SDL.h>

class Game {
public:
    Game();
    ~Game();

    void init(const char* title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height, bool fullscreen);

    void handleEvents();
    void update();
    void render();
    void clean();

    bool running() {return isRunning;}
private:
    bool isRunning;
    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
};
```

Comment: What is your compiler? If you are using MinGW you should have used `pacman` to install sdl2. `pacman` is the package manager in msys2 and is the recommended method to install MinGW in VSCode: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw)

Comment: Why do you have two different errors in the question? `SDL.h: No such file or directory` and `unresolved external symbol SDL_main`. Which one is it?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat 'The SDL.h: No such file or directory' is when I hover over it in VSCode. The other error is the console/terminal that prints out this error. I can autocomplete 'SDL.h' in the IDE, but when I press build or run then it "locates" the error.

Comment: @drescherjm I've used msys2 to install MinGW, but not to install sdl2 with it. Trying that.

Comment: The errors that VSC itself shows don't really matter for now. Get the code to actually compile first, then you can configure intellisense.

Comment: But first, you need to decide which compiler you're going to be using, MSVC or MinGW. Currently you're using MSVC, but MSYS2 is for MinGW.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I was having similar trouble with SDL2 as well. I can't be sure what your problem is, but a solution that helped me was including the file structure of the dll in the include compiler directive, for example, I did:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
```

not

```
#include <SDL.h>
```

Not sure if that helps, as I do not use Visual Studio. However its likely worth trying.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, also doesn't work sadly. Same error :(

Comment: When SDL2 is used correctly, `SDL2/` should automatically get added to the include path.

Comment: But remember my folder structure and how SDL2 gets implemented, or are you already? @HolyBlackCat

Comment: @Arktikus Your folder structure doesn't really matter, as long as your include paths are automatically configured by CMake. If it does its job correctly, `<SDL.h>` by itself will work. Also, if you use any of the SDL2 plugins (SDL2_image, etc), they do `"SDL.h"`, and won't work if that header is not in the include path (or if you don't plop all their headers in one directory, I guess).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Sadly still not working. Tried both.